# RVM-capistrano gem, cannot find ruby-1.9.3-p0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rvm-capistrano

I installed `ruby-1.9.3-p286` on my server with RVM, and confirmed it with `ruby -v` in the terminal.

However, following the instructions from [RVM-Capistrano gem integration](https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/),

```
set :rvm_ruby_string,  ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"")
require 'rvm/capistrano'
```

and running `cap deploy`, it still insists on running `ruby-1.9.3-p0`, and of course it can't find it.

Manually opening up irb in Terminal and running `ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"")` returns `ruby-1.9.3-p286`, so I am puzzled why it keeps asking for `ruby-1.9.3-p0`.

Anyone encountered a similar situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just struggling with a similar problem, googled for a solution, and found your question.  Anyway, in my case, I had specified the Ruby version to be `1.9.3-p327` everywhere: in my `.bashrc` file (`rvm --default use 1.9.3-p327`), in the application's `.rvmrc` file (`rvm use 1.9.3-p327@my_app_name`), etc., and I still got this output when commanding `cap deploy` or `cap deploy:setup`:

```
*** [err :: localhost] ruby-1.9.3-p286 is not installed.
 ** [out :: localhost] To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p286'
*** [err :: localhost] Error: RVM was unable to use '1.9.3@my_app_name'
```

Turns out the problem was in Capistrano's configuration file, `my_app_name/config/deploy.rb`. It defined the Ruby version like this:

```
set :rvm_ruby_string,           "1.9.3@#{application}"
```

Why Capistrano turned this into `1.9.3-p286` is still a mystery to me. Anyway, I added the Ruby patchlevel to the line, like this:

```
set :rvm_ruby_string,           "1.9.3-p327@#{application}"
```

And then `cap deploy:setup` and `cap deploy` started working.

Furthermore, I found out that Capistrano has added the possibility of using the Ruby version given in the application's `.rvmrc` file ([see this](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano/pull/4)), so you can just set that line to

```
set :rvm_ruby_string,           :local
```

and never have to touch it again, even if you change the Ruby version in `.rvmrc`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I am sure it will come in handy in the near future. What I did in the meantime was stick with Heroku :P I was trying to deploy to Bluehost but I don't think that was a good idea anyway. Will do it on VPS someday